# SMTP Email Issue in Php

Tags: php, email

I am trying to send email in php using `SMTP`. But don't know why it is not returning anything.
It is working fine without `SMTP`.
Do I need to add any extra or anything on `Hosting Server` ?

**My Code:**

```
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
$mail->SMTPDebug  = 0;
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
$mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
$mail->Port = 587;
$mail->IsHTML(true);
$mail->Username = "example@gmail.com";
$mail->Password = "password";

$mail->SetFrom($email);
$mail->Subject = $subject;
$mail->Body = $mail_body;
$mail->AddAddress("info@neelcomputech.com");

if(!$mail->Send())
{
    alert('Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo);
}
else
{
    alert('Success');
}
```

Comment: `alert` is javascript. Your code is in php. Try using `echo` instead of `alert` and see if that prints out anything

Comment: @asprin, changed it. But it is not sending email. How can i check error ? I am new to php so don't have any idea.

Comment: What is getting printed on page?

Comment: I cant see anything that's why I have posted here. Basically, I am dotnet developer so have less idea for error messages in php.

Comment: That's strange. It should either have printed "Success" or "Mailer Error:..." If you're getting a blank page, it could mean the code isn't running at all.

Comment: I have checked in Firebug, It is showing Internal Server Error and There is blank Response.

Comment: @asprin, Finally got error : `Class 'PHPMailer' not found` on hosting path. What to do now ?

Comment: It's pretty self explanatory, isn't it? You need to include the class file before using it.

Comment: Which class ? Will I get any readymade class or what ?

Comment: https://code.google.com/a/apache-extras.org/p/phpmailer/source/browse/trunk/class.phpmailer.php

Answer (score 1):

please try this u will be getting the solution

http://webnaar.wordpress.com/2014/03/17/smtp-mailler-for-php/

Comment: provide explanation with some demo link. only links are not good answers.

Answer (score 0):

You need to download the zip file from this repositry : [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer)
Then you need to extract the `PHPMailerAutoload.php`, `class.phpmailer.php` and `class.smtp.php` files into your directory of the script. Also add `require 'PHPMailerAutoload.php';` to the top of your PHP file. The repositry under the [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer)
has a good explanation of how to get it running under **Installation & loading**.

Also note what aspin said in the comments that you shouldn't be using alert(); use echo instead.

```
if(!$mail->Send()) {
    echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo "Success";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code - -

```
    include("class.phpmailer.php"); 
    // You can download class.phpmailer.php from 
    // https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/class.phpmailer.php

    $mail = new PHPMailer();
    $mail->IsSMTP();
    $mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
    $mail->SMTPDebug  = 1;
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
    $mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
    $mail->Port = 587;
    $mail->IsHTML(true);
    $mail->Username = "myid@gmail.com";
    $mail->Password = "mypassword";

    $mail->SetFrom('myid@gmail.com');
    $mail->Subject = 'Test EM';
    $mail->Body = 'Hi!';
    $mail->AddAddress("myid@gmail.com");

    if(!$mail->Send()) {
        print('Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo);
    } else {
        print('Success');
    }
```

Let me know if still you face any issue.